# Can you set strategy option to global gitignore?

Tags: git, git-config

E.g. I'm constantly doing this in my command options

> git rebase -Xignore-all-space [other branch]

Is there a way to default that into git config?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a config option to set default strategy options, but it is possible to use an alias for this.  In general, strategy options that involve space would not be good for the config because they tend to affect correctness.

An example alias might look like the following:

```
git config --global alias.sprebase "rebase -m -Xignore-all-space"
```